# Where should interceptors reside in Spring application

Tags: java, spring

I am developing a spring framework based java web application.
I have multiple spring configuration files.  One servlet xml and few other applicationContext.xml.
Now where should I put my interceptors and Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define multiple contexts in a Spring based application.
applicationContext.xml lets you define the spring beans for the spring web application context. And  spring1-servlet.xml (the name of sevlet xml may differ) lets you define beans associated with the servlet application context. There can be multiple servlets defined in a spring web application. Each servlet has its own xml file.

The beans defined in servlet application context cannot be referenced outside this xml. But beans residing in this application can reference the beans defined by applicationContext.xml

[image]

You can define multiple contexts in a Spring based application.
applicationContext.xml lets you define the spring beans for the spring web application context. And  spring1-servlet.xml (the name of sevlet xml may differ) lets you define beans associated with the servlet application context. There can be multiple servlets defined in a spring web application. Each servlet has its own xml file.

The beans defined in servlet application context cannot be referenced outside this xml. But beans residing in this application can reference the beans defined by applicationContext.xml

Comment: The import thing here is `ApplicationContext` not xml as it could also be based on property files or java based configuration. The xml is just one of the (partial) representations of the `ApplicationContext` configuration.